# Image Clickable Inside Div

Tags: html, image

Here is my code. No matter what I try I can not get it to work...
Thanks for the help!

I need to make the img clickable.

```
<img class="ls-l" style="left: 550px; top: 30px;" src="images/slider_img_02.png" alt="Image layer" data-ls="
                offsetxin: bottom;
                offsetxout: 0;
                offsetyin: 500;
                offsetyout: bottom;
                easingin: easeInOutCubic;
                durationin: 1200;
                durationout: 50;
                delayin: 200;
            ">  

        </div>
```

Comment: Wrap anchor around image tag. `<a href="#link"><img .. /></a>` will do

Comment: This is the first thing I did and it's still not clickable. I'm wondering if it has to do with it being withing a slider.

Comment: Post the full code that you can be used to replicate the issue.

Comment: Try using jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2psh0nhu/1/

Comment: Code in your fiddle works just fine.

Comment: It's stripping the code out when it is live and viewed in inspect element...

Comment: Where is your live site?

Comment: That's good. Reply to the thread and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

You can set the Anchor tag to fill the entire parent.

```
<div>
    <a href="..." style="display: block; height: 100%">
        <img src="..." alt=".." />
    </a>
</div>
```

and the entire `<div>` will be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put img tag inside anchor tag as follows to make image clickable

```
<a href="#">
<img class="ls-l" style="left: 550px; top: 30px;" src="images/slider_img_02.png" alt="Image layer" data-ls="
                offsetxin: bottom;
                offsetxout: 0;
                offsetyin: 500;
                offsetyout: bottom;
                easingin: easeInOutCubic;
                durationin: 1200;
                durationout: 50;
                delayin: 200;
            " />  
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <img class="ls-l" style="left: 550px; top: 30px; cursor: pointer;" src="images/slider_img_02.png" alt="Image layer" onclick="window.parent.open('#link','_blank');" data-ls="
                offsetxin: bottom;
                offsetxout: 0;
                offsetyin: 500;
                offsetyout: bottom;
                easingin: easeInOutCubic;
                durationin: 1200;
                durationout: 50;
                delayin: 200;
            ">
```